# Why do I get different results when comparing strings after using different concatenation in Java?

Tags: java

i was working on the basic java program and i found verry funny thing which i am sharing with you. foo() gives output (s==s1) = false and bar gives (s==s1) = true.

I want to know why this happens.

```
public class StringTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    foo();
    bar();
  }
  public static void foo(){
    String s = "str4";
    String s1 = "str" + s.length();
    System.out.println("(s==s1) = " + (s1==s));
  }
  public static void bar(){
    String s = "str4";
    String s1 = "str" + "4";
    System.out.println("(s==s1) = " + (s1==s));
 }
}
```

Comment: if you're trying to compare String values, you should be doing [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Note: HTML tags don't work here to format code.

Comment: I wonder how man bugs out there relate to this issue... ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the latter case, the compiler optimizes the string concatenation. As this can be done at compile time, both reference the same constant string object.

In the former case, the `length()` call can't be optimized during compile time. At runtime, a new string object is created, which is not identical to the string constant (but equal to it)

Comment: but what if i will change the value of s1 in bar() after ompersion..??

Comment: Java strings are immutable, so either it will reference another string constant (when assigning/appending a literal), or a new string is created at runtime (e.g. by assigning/appending something dynamically)

Comment: Everything would be clear if you just use intern method of a String object. Each unique string has only one representation in memory. A String object can hold either a string itself or be a wrapper. If it is a wrapper, the representation can be retrieved by intern method.

Answer (score 3):

The string catenation in `bar()` can be done at compile time, because it's an expression composed of nothing but compile-time constants. Although the length of the String `s` is obviously known at compile time, the compiler doesn't know that `length()` returns that known value, so it won't be used as a constant.

Comment: +1, but no one has mentioned using `.equals()` to compare string equality?

Comment: @Mikaveli: I believe @Chakravyooh knows about that, but it's irrelevant to the question. If you use `equals()`, then the interesting behavior here is simply hidden, and where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 2):

When you write a line of code like this:

```
String s1 = "str" + "4";
```

then the compiler is smart enough to optimize this to:

```
String s1 = "str4";
```

Literal strings in Java are managed in a string pool. When you have two literal strings that have the same content (such as `s` and `s1` in your second example), then just one `String` object will be created which will be shared by the two variables.

The `==` operator in Java checks if two variables refer to the same object. Since there is only one `String` object in the second example, `s == s1` will be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

- `String s1 = "str" + s.length();`
- `String s1 = "str" + "4";`

In first case s.length() will return a value of type **int**, In second case The type is **String**
Even though the number is 4 in both the cases but types are not the same :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the fact that foo() is probably creating an new String instance in s.length()(.toString()), where as bar() is just concatenating a constant. I don't know the nitty gritty of it, but my gut tells me it in that direction

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to guess I would say that the java compiler performs some optimization onto bar(). At compiletime it is clear that "str" + "4" can be replaced by "str4" which (since Strings are immutable objects) is indeed the very same object as "str4"-String used for the s-initialization.

Within foo() the optimization is not that streight forward. In general the value s1-variable cannot be predicted very easily (indeed this example is quite streight forward). So the java compiler will produce two different variables for s and s1.

The "==" operator does not compare the value of the Strings! It checks whether these are the same Objects. To compare the values of the Strings use the "equals" method like this:

```
String s = "str4";
String s1 = "str" + s.length();
System.out.println("(s==s1) = " + (s1.equals(s2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try playing with intern method of String class. Java keeps something like dictionary where all different strings are stored. When you create a string object which can be evaluated at compile time, Java searches it in its dictionary. If it founds the string, it stores only a reference to this string (which is actually returned by intern method).

You should notice that:
`"str4" == ("str" + "str4".length())` returns false, but
`"str4" == ("str" + "str4".length()).intern()` returns true, because the only "wrapper" is a different object.